# Overloading operator `:=` in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Why I can't create or overload operator `:=` in my class in C++?

Is there are some list operators that I can overload?

I can only overload, or also create some new custom operators?

Comment: By reload, I assume you mean overload?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because no such operator exists in C++. You cannot roll your own operators because you would need to modify the grammar of the language for the parser to recognize them.

You can find a list of the available operators [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x04xhy0h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (or better yet by reading the standard if you can get a copy).

Finally, be advised that overloading operators like there is no tomorrow is a mistake that pretty much every C++ beginner makes; operators are really nothing more than functions, and unless there is a very good case to be made for overloading an operator most of the time it's a better idea to just write a plain function for your class instead. For example, `std::string` does *not* have an `operator*` even though it could be argued that it's convenient to write

```
string sleepy = string("z") * 40;
```

Comment: I don't see any reason not to have that string operator; it's a glaring omission from the `std::basic_string` template class. :)

Comment: @Kaz: Furthermore, there should also be an implicit conversion to `class troll` ;-).

Answer (score 1):

The operators you can overload are:
[image]

Perhaps you meant the assignment or the equals operator.

```
class Object{

public:

    ///Overload The Assignment Operator
    Object& operator=(const Object& objectIn);

    ///Overload The Equals Operator
    bool operator == (const Object & rhs) const;

protected:
private:
};
```